# Is there ANY possible way to make TextMate's ⌘-F regex by default?

Tags: regex, textmate

TextMate newbie here.

I hate to have to grab my mouse to click that Regular Expressions box nearly every time I search.

**EDIT:** the Regex check box becomes unchecked anytime after using ⌘-F in Safari.

Comment: I check it and it stays checked. At least as long as I have TextMate open. Version 1.5.9 (1510) on 10.6.4.

Comment: I'm on the same. Try using ⌘-F in safari, then coming back to TextMate and doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of TextMate?  On mine it remembers across launches/reboots.  Go to *TextMate -> Preferences*, then *Software Update*.  Under *Watch For:* select *Cutting-Edge*.  Then select *Check Now* and install the update.

Comment: I was on build 1509. Thanks for letting me know about the cutting edge builds. I just updated  1589. Unfortunately I have the same behavior. But please see my edited post, because I originally explained the problem wrong.

Comment: I actually tested this (Cmd+F in TextMate, switch to Safari, Cmd+F, Switch to TextMate, Cmd+F) and it still stays checked.  Same with using Safari's Cmd+F between launches of TextMate.  At this point I'm stumped...

Comment: even when hitting the next button (or cmd-G) in safari?

Comment: Nope, it works fine.  Can you post the exact sequence?  i.e. (Launch Safari) -> (Launch TextMate) -> (Find, check "Regular Expression") -> (Switch to Safari) -> (Find and Cmd+G) -> etc.?  That would help if you could post an exact sequence that will duplicate the problem.  Be sure to start with TextMate and Safari both quit, end with them both quit, and go through the sequence twice to be sure.

Comment: Follow-up: I've just found a way.  Start with both closed.  (Launch Safari) -> (Launch TextMate) -> (Cmd+F, check Regex, Cmd+W) -> (Switch to Safari) -> (Cmd+F) -> (_Type Something in the Search Field_) -> (Cmg+G) -> (Esc) -> (Switch to TextMate) -> (Cmd+F).  That results in the _text you entered filling the search field_ and the _regex box unchecked_.  It seems that what triggers this is when you actually enter something in the Safari search field; TextMate takes that text and fills its search box, with the regex box unchecked.

Comment: Of course, knowing that does nothing to fix the problem... you may want to contact TextMate support on this one since that's something that really shouldn't happen (I think).  Be sure to include the exact sequence of events that triggers it.

Comment: thanks for all your help, I was thinking I should do that.